# Nginx Proxy Pass parameter issue

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Here is a URL : http://123.com/stat/api/abc?a=123

if I want to set proxy pass to : http://456.com/api/abc?a=123

My nginx config as below :

```
server {
        listen         80;
        server_name    123.com;
        location /stat {
             proxy_pass http://456.com;
        }
}
```

And this is not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution.
The final config as below :

```
location /stat/ {
        proxy_pass http://456.com/;
}
```

the end of slash in location section and proxy_pass section must be have.